# Determining Class from String representation of an Object

Tags: java

Consider I am given an array of `Classes` and string representation of an `Object`.  How can I get which `Class` this `Object` belongs to?

I thought of this approach but I don't know how to achieve it:

> Iterating over Class array and then getting all instances of that
>   class.Then convert each instance to its String representation and then
>   check if it equals given String.

The problem I'm having is how do I get all `Instances` of that `Class`?
We can use `getInstance()` if all are `Singleton` class but what if not?

Please clarify my if I have any misunderstanding.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Class_instance {

  public static void main(String args[]){
     List<Class> class_list = new ArrayList<Class>();
     Test_class x = new Test_class();
     Test y = new Test();

     class_list.add(x.getClass());
     class_list.add(y.getClass());

     String ex = x.toString();
     }
}
```

How to know what class `ex` represents here?

Comment: Define "string representation"? Do you mean the result of a `toString()` call? Or do you have some standard all your objects adhere to? What objects are we talking about? Honestly, if we are talking about random objects, then, sorry, your job is pretty much impossible without more work than this is worth.

Comment: Yes.... i mean toString() call only.Sorry I didnt understand what standard you mean.I am giving this example which I tried.

Comment: toString() is not something that is specified. Every programmer can decide what a toString method for his classes return in toString(). it only should be a good representation of the class, but that does NOT mean that it has to contain the class name, for example. So, if you want to write your code for all possible classes, it's impossible. If you write your code only for YOUR classes than you can invent some schema for your toString() methods, to ensure it contains the qualitifed class name. Without your use case, it's hard to say.

Comment: Ok got your point....but even in that case how do we get all instances of given Classes

Comment: If you control all the classes, then you could, for example, add a static list to each class and add the object to the list in the constructor... Of course, the whole thing smell still like a bad idea, but I assume it's simple an exercise.

Comment: Ok....yeah you mean to create a list of all objects of each class and call that list directly

Comment: There are many, many ways to do it. Doesn't change the fact that it's probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned we need to know what string representation means.

In most application (AFAIK) instanceof should suffice to check if object belong to a certain class or not .  Another way is to define a overwrite the toString method

```
public class House {
    public String address;
    public String type;

    public House(String add){
        this.address = add;
    }  

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (address + "-" + type) ;
    }
}
```

If given a String sample = "Hogwart-Castle";  You can use the following :

```
houseObj.toString().equals(sample);
```

Comment: @sean...thanks for the answer....I got your approach but how do we get all objects of class House.....I mean how to get houseObj

Comment: @BhavyaSharma You need to show e code for your main class for us to advice you . AFAIK that is no single function call that lets you get all the object created within runtime of e program. You will need a datastructure to store all your object creation.

Comment: @sean....ok so that means for achieving this behavior I need to overwrite toString() method.I tried something like this it worked:class_list.get(i).getSimpleName().equals(ex) .I have overridden toString() method like this " return this.getClass().getSimpleName();"

Comment: That means there is no way to get all runtime instances of a Class?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer - no, this won't work.

The `toString()` method returns a [textual representation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) of the object, but there is no guarantee this will include the class name.  For example, for `String`s, `toString()` returns the value of the string.  In particular *any* textual representation could come from a string.

If you have a specific list of classes you want to look for (and they have identifiable values), you could write regexes which would identify their `toString` values.

Using the `Class` object directly is more likely to be what you're after here:

```
  public static void main(String [] args){
      Class[] possibleClasses= {String.class, Integer.class};
      System.out.println(identifyClass("string", possibleClasses));
      System.out.println(identifyClass(4, possibleClasses));
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("raw")
  public static Class identifyClass(Object o, Class[] possibleClasses){
      // Ignore null inputs
      if (o==null){
          return null;
      }

      // Find the first entry which matches o
      for (Class c : possibleClasses){
          if (c.isInstance(o)){
              return c;
          }
      }

      // If no matches are found, return null.
      return null;
  }
```

Although that said, maybe this would be enough?

```
System.out.println(ex.getClass().getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you own the classes you want to search, you can keep the track of their instances by creating a new class (I called it `MyObject`) with a static field that you fill when a new object of that class is created, and then extending the classes you want to keep track with this new class.

```
public class MyObject {
    private static Map<Class<?>, List<WeakReference<?>>> instances = new HashMap<>();

    public MyObject() {
        if (!instances.containsKey(getClass())) {
            instances.put(getClass(), new ArrayList<>());
        }
        instances.get(getClass()).add(new WeakReference<>(this));
    }

    public static List<Object> getInstances(List<Class<?>> classes) {
        List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
            if (instances.containsKey(clazz)) {
                Iterator<WeakReference<?>> iterator = instances.get(clazz).iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    WeakReference<?> ref = iterator.next();
                    if (ref.get() == null) {
                        iterator.remove();
                    } else {
                        result.add(ref.get());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog d1 = new Dog("I'm a dog");
        Dog d2 = new Dog("I'm an animal");
        Cat c1 = new Cat("I'm an animal");

        List<Class<?>> classList = new ArrayList<>();
        classList.add(Dog.class);
        find("I'm an animal", classList); // Found a Dog

        classList.add(Cat.class);
        find("I'm an animal", classList); // Found a Dog and a Cat

        find("I'm a dog", classList); // Found a Dog

    }

    private static void find(String str, List<Class<?>> classes) {
        for (Object o : MyObject.getInstances(classes)) {
            if (o.toString().equals(str)) {
                System.out.println("Found a " + o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `Dog` class (and similarly the `Cat` class) looks like this:

```
public class Dog extends MyObject {
    String description;

    public Dog(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Beware that `toString()` doesn't return a unique representation of an object (as shown in my example), unless you have full control over the `toString()` of that objects and you ensure it yourself.